# Prime as an argument of command

Tags: programming

Suppose we are in math-mode and I want to use command \E with the following behaviour. If one or two primes follow the command, i.e. \E' or \E'', then I want to have in these cases certain expressions, say A or B. In all the other cases I want to have merely E independently what precedes or follows the \E. Here are exames

1. `$any \E' some$` -> any A some
2. `$any \E'' some$` -> any B some
3. `$any \E some$` -> any E some

I dont want to use the command in a longer form like `\E{arg1}{arg2}` but only  in  `\E'`, `\E''` forms. Let, for example,

```
\def\E#1#2{my code}
```

Then the problem arises when using something like

```
$$
 x \E' \sin x 
$$
```

Or

```
$$
A \E b
$$
```

Because "b" should not be considered as an argument of `\E` in the latter case and the same reason for a slash in front of sine in the former case.

Comment: First you should avoid `$$..$$`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

Comment: You ought to be able to do so using `etoolbox` and `xparse`

Comment: I do not like to use packages if I want really just a simple trick or  single action. Packages are mostly monstrouses

Answer (score 9):

You might enjoy a generic interface for defining as many commands of the same kind as you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\declareprimedcommand} { m m m m }
 {% #1 = command to define
  % #2 = text for no prime
  % #3 = text for one prime
  % #4 = text for two primes
  \maximav_primedcommand:Nnnn #1 { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \maximav_primedcommand:Nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4
 {
  \cs_new_protected:Npn #1
   {
    \peek_charcode_remove:NTF '
     { \peek_charcode_remove:NTF ' { #4 } { #3 } }
     { #2 }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\declareprimedcommand{\E}{x}{y}{z}

\begin{document}
$a \E b$

$a \E' b$

$a \E'' b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again. The only pity is the fact that xparse monstrous should be used

Comment: @maximav You could take the underlying implementation and recode it yourself: `xparse` here is more syntactic sugar than anything else, and while the `\peek_...` functions are tricky they are not that long.

Comment: @maximav: Do you see any drawbacks of `xparse`? Normally it's one line in your header and you can use all the facilities of this great package.

Answer (score 8):

Here an approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\@ifprime#1{\@ifnextchar'{\@firstoftwo{#1}}}
\newcommand\E{\@ifprime\E@i\E@}
\def\E@i{\@ifprime{B}{A}}
\def\E@{E}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[ x \E' \sin x  \]

\[ x \E'' \sin x  \]

\[ x \E \sin x  \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice job! I would never guess. Is it a simplest (shortest) solution? Three auxiliary commands... Anyway, my THANKS!

Comment: By the way, Marco. The command names are very simple - \E@ or \E@i. Is this dengerous? I mean possible overlapping of the names with other packages whose variable names we cannot control.

Comment: @maximav Use `\newcommand` instead of `\def`

Comment: I would prefere an independent extension of the \E@... codes above to the following situations: \commonE{E}{a}{b}{c} with the usage like \newcommand{\myE}[4]{\commonE{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}

Comment: @maximav: egreg shows a suitable solution.